# Open XML SDK 2.0 breaking changes between 2.0.3920.0 and 2.0.5022.0

Tags: xml, sdk, openoffice.org

I have a project which is using  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll 2.0.3920.0. However, I want this to be upgraded to the 2.0.5022.0 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en#filelist). **Note that there is change only in the revision number of the version.** I removed the older reference and added the new one and It compiles fine. However, I need to know If there are any runtime breaking changes in the new version and I am not able to find the same after some hours of searching. Sure, I should (and would) test all the functionalities. However, just wanted to know If anybody is already aware of any breaking changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some errors upgrading I will come back if there is a problem!?!?!

Comment: Right now I have found no documentation regarding changes but get some errors where it looks like they have changed namespace and names on 

TextFontAlignValues  
TextTabAlignValues 
TextAnchoringValues
Shape3D
Scene3D
AppVersion
AppNonVisualDrawingProperties

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Several values, such as `FontSize`, have changed their type from `UInt32Value` to `StringValue`. `BooleanValues` has been removed: `LatentStyleException`, renamed to `LatentStyleExceptionInfo`, new uses the type `OnOffValue` which is implicitly convertible from Booleans.